# what is good material for 100C to 130C for heat box

Tags: insulation, materials

I am trying to design a small box (25" x 25" x 25") for an uniform heating oven. I am planning to heat around 100 C (212 F) to 130 C (266 F).

I was searching for several material such as green board(<52 C), plywood(<93 C), polycarbonate(<115 C), acry plastic(<71 C) etc. and I found that most of the wood is not recommended to use more than 100 C continuously.

Any recommendation for the material that is cheap and easy to fabricate and also able to use at temperature around 100 C-130 C?

Thank you

Comment: I know some cement board is rated up to 200F, and you might be able to find some that's rated higher. However, it sounds like a combination a metal interior, an insulated middle, and cement board (or similar) exterior would be your best bet. Though, if this heat box is used for food preparation, you'll need a non-reactive metal on the inside.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, construction questions like this are off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sheet metal. Insulate with rockwool. Unfortunately your size seems to be just beyond what you can likely find in a household oven, which is (in used condition) generally the least expensive way to get a metal box of roughly that size, with heating elements, insulation, and a thermostat already installed.